# C++: Class method using function defined in main

Tags: c++, scope

So I have a class:

```
class MyClass
public:
    printSomeStuff() { //Including implementation here to save space
        print(data);
    }

private:
    int data;
```

And a main program, with a template function defined outside:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T val) {
    cout << val;
}

int main() {
    MyClass a;
    a.printSomeStuff();
}
```

The idea is that I could move `MyClass` somewhere else and be fine, but a new `print` function would need to be defined based on the scenario. Typically this would just be a `cout`.

If I try to actually use this style of coding, though, I get an error because `print` is not defined in MyClass.cpp.

How should I address this issue?

Comment: Templates are heavy things, if you want to move MyClass somewhere, use headers and linking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move your `print()` function into a header (and a suitable namespace) and include it into the translation units where it is needed, e.g.:

```
// print.h
#ifndef INCLUDED_PRINT
#define INCLUDED_PRINT
#include <iostream>
namespace utilities {
    template <typename T>
    void print(T const& val) {
        std::cout << val;
    }
}
#endif
```

You'd then include this header into the translation where it is used, e.g.

```
// MyClass.h
#ifndef INCLUDED_MYCLASS
#define INCLUDED_MYCLASS
#include "print.h"

class MyClass
public:
    printSomeStuff() { //Including implementation here to save space
        utilities::print(data);
    }

private:
    int data;
};
#endif
```

Comment: I like this idea, but I do have one remaining question. Why do you advise creating a new namespace for the print function? Couldn't I get away with simply using std?

Comment: @Rstevoa Free floating functions are never a good idea. Namespace do not just protect you from name conflicts but also group your things together. If one reads your code and he will see `print()` he might ask, is this a static method, a member method or where does it come from? If he sees `utilities::print()` though, he will recognize the namespace and understand that its a "standalone" function used throughout the application (which will probably come from `util.h` or something similar). One could also argue that namespaces increase consistency as the call is more similar to static methods.

Comment: @Paranaix: good point - forget to mention it... (I updated the code)

Comment: @Rstevoa: The namespace isn't strictly necessary. However, when you combine multiple sources there is quickly the chance that different programmers have used the same name. For example `print()` is a likely name to be used to write to the screen but the details are likely to be different and two implementations with the same name at global scope will be a conflict. Even if your current code is just a couple of lines large, you are better off in the long run to use namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Put your template definition in its own header file and include it in your class implementation file.

That said, with something as trivial as printing, it may be must as easy to do it in the `printSomeStuff` method entirely.  The extra indirection isn't really buying you anything.

Answer (score 0):

The header in which print template is defined has to be accessible from the header in which MyClass is defined, but not necessarily from main, so you could move it to a separated header and include it from MyClass.hpp or even MyClass.cc